# Сделать первый верхний пункт списка активным (тем самым раскрытым)

Tags: css

Приветствую,
маленькая проблемка помогите, плиз,
с решением, нужно сделать первый верхний пункт списка активным (тем самым раскрытым)

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/grozevchik/SdbFJ/)

Помогите, пожалуйста, в решении.

**Обновление**

Прошу прощения но по всей видимости я плохо обьяснил суть вопроса,
то что первый пункт нужен как активный тем самым открытая картинка это да, но при наведении мышки на пункт ниже нужно чтобы он становился активным, а первая (верхняя строка) переставала быть активной тем самым пряталось изображение, чтобы небыло задержки цыкла по всем пунктам списка.

/**/

1. Изначально первый пункт списка активный (видна картинка в этом пункте списка)
2. Когда наводим мышку на пункт списка ниже то теперь этот пунк становится активным + выезжает картинка.

Comment: что это значит?

Comment: Можно `:hover` заменить на класс: http://jsfiddle.net/SdbFJ/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SdbFJ/5/ суть в том, чтобы игнорить .active если у меню :hover

Comment: @grozevchik так вы идею поняли ? думаю не сложно сделать чтобы было как надо.

Comment: попробуйте понять что сделано, не получается показывайте что именно попробовали, я за вас делать не буду всё.

Comment: да я и не просил что бы за меня делали))
вроде бы работает 

.mh-menu li:hover > img {
    left: 300px;
 opacity: 1;
}

как здесь подправить, при наведении на строку списка
картинку смещает немного вправо

Answer (score 1):

Решение должно быть обязательно на css? на JQuery эта проблема решается легко и просто:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mh-menu li").hover(function() {
    $(".mh-menu li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.mh-menu {
  height: 385px;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.mh-menu li {
  width: 300px;
  list-style: none;
}

.mh-menu li a {
  display: block;
  width: 280px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  background: transparent;
  height: 97px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.mh-menu li.active a {
  background-color: rgba(174, 54, 55, 0.9);
}

.mh-menu li:hover a {
  background-color: rgba(195, 210, 67, 0.9)
}

.mh-menu li:nth-child(3):hover a {
  background-color: rgba(211, 132, 57, 0.9);
}

.mh-menu li:nth-child(4):hover a {
  background-color: rgba(142, 116, 99, 0.9);
}

.mh-menu li a span {
  display: block;
}

.mh-menu li a span:first-child {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ddd;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-family: 'Alegreya SC', Georgia, serif;
}

.mh-menu li a span:nth-child(2) {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: 'Alegreya SC', Georgia, serif;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: color 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: color 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transition: color 0.2s linear;
  transition: color 0.2s linear;
}

.mh-menu li.active span:nth-child(2) {
  color: #fff;
}

.mh-menu li img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.mh-menu li.active img {
  left: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <!-- Codrops top bar -->
  <div class="codrops-top">
  </div>
  <!--/ Codrops top bar -->
  <ul class="mh-menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="#"><span>Art Director</span> <span>Henry James</span></a><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="image01" /></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Production Coordinator</span> <span>Francis Morgan</span></a><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="image02" /></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Sound</span> <span>Kevin Schneider</span></a><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="image03" /></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Casting</span> <span>Benjamin Zakalis</span></a><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="image04" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```